# Keyboard and Mouse callbacks in GLUT

Tags: events, glut

I'm using OpenGL via GLUT in Ubuntu.

```
While writing text in a text editor, the first keystroke is printed immediately.
But if we keep pressing the key, it waits for a moment and then prints a trail of that character.
```

This is to reduce the sensitivity while typing.

With GLUT, function callbacks for keyboard behave like that.

```
glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
glutKeyboardUpFunc( keyboard_up );
```

Now if we keep pressing a key, there is a considerable delay between the first and the second call of `keyboard` ( and `keyboard_up`) function. But in real gaming, this not should be the case.

**Question 1:** How to solve the problem?

**Question 2:** `keyboard_up` gets called even if I press and hold a key. Why so? I think it is supposed to get called only when I release it. Moreover, this also suffers from the above jerk problem.

**Question 3:** For `glutMouseFunc( mouse )`, the `mouse` function gets called whenever we press or release a mouse button. I want this too to get called repeatedly if I press and hold my mouse button, and that too without jerk. How to do so?

Comment: I've edited your question to replace "OpenGL" with "GLUT" since it's actually nothing to do with OpenGL.

Comment: Short tangential answer: games don't use GLUT.

Answer (score 2):

`glutIgnoreKeyRepeat` to ignore auto-repeated keystrokes. (that resolves Questions 1 & 2.)

There, unfortunately, isn't an option to make the mouse button's get called repeatedly. You can, however, **create variables recording the mouse button states**. And then read those when you need to know if a button is down. Just as good, or better. (Question 3)

Further Description: Recording key-states in variables for repeated use over many frames

Typically in games when you walk forward using a key, they don't rely on the OS's key-repeat. That can be adjusted so the repeat will likely be much slower then your game-loop cycle. That will create jerky movement that could be smoothed out if it was calculated on a per-frame basis.

One of the simplest ways to cut out that jerky movement, is to check that keys state on a per-frame basis. You can do that with function call's, that however will add a bit of unneeded overhead. So instead, you can record the key-state locally in the program. Since GLUT defines a key with `char`, there are only 255 different key's that you might get. So you only need an array 255 bytes long to store each key's state.

But then there are the 3 mouse buttons. 3 bytes, 1 for each mouse button. The ending result of all this is:

```
#define BUTTON_UP   0
#define BUTTON_DOWN 1

#define MOUSE_LEFT   0
#define MOUSE_MIDDLE 1
#define MOUSE_RIGHT  2

unsigned char keyState[255];
unsigned char mouseState[3];

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    keyState[key] = BUTTON_DOWN;
}

void keyboard_up(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    keyState[key] = BUTTON_UP;
}

void mouse(int button, int button_state, int x, int y)
{
    #define state ( (button_state == GLUT_DOWN) ? BUTTON_DOWN : BUTTON_UP ) // shortens later code

    switch (button)
    {
        case GLUT_MOUSE_LEFT:
            mouseState[MOUSE_LEFT] = state;
            break;
        case GLUT_MOUSE_MIDDLE:
            mouseState[MOUSE_MIDDLE] = state;
            break;
        case GLUT_MOUSE_RIGHT:
            mouseState[MOUSE_RIGHT] = state;
            break;
    }

    #undef state // make sure the defined "state" code above is only used in this function
}

void main()
{
    // some fancy code

    if (keyState[(unsigned char)'W'] == BUTTON_DOWN) // Walk forward
    {
        // W is being pressed! Time to walk.
    }

    if (keyState[(unsigned char)'1'] == BUTTON_DOWN) // render in Wire-Frame
    {
        // toggle wire-frame rendering

        // this key toggles wire-frame mode. We dont want it changing every frame,
        // Or it would keep changing to fast for the user to keep track of.
        // so we'll just say the key is up. Then it wont switch back before the user
        // is ready.
        keyState['1'] = BUTTON_UP;
    }

    // some more fancy code
}
```

Comment: `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat` does not allow to repeat key strokes as long as it is pressed. I want it to repeat without that jerk after the first keystroke, which usually happens in dynamic games.

Comment: For question 3, we can use `glutMouseFunc` along with `glutMotionFunc` or `glutPassiveMotionFunc`. But still this won't work if the mouse is still.

Comment: Made an edit. Should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

`glutSetKeyRepeat` is faster than `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat`, so says [this](http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~matos/cg/docs/manual/glutSetKeyRepeat.3GLUT.html) man page

> **glutIgnoreKeyRepeat** can prevent these auto repeated keystrokes from being reported as keyboard or special callbacks, but there is still some minimal overhead by the X server to continually stream KeyPress events to the GLUT application. The **glutSetKeyRepeat** routine can be used to actually disable the global sending of auto repeated KeyPress events.

Put this in your init/main

```
glutSetKeyRepeat(GLUT_KEY_REPEAT_OFF);
```